Debug logs for exchangelib
I'm using exchangelib to connect to an on-premise Exchange server as part of some pytest code and getting the error "Failed to get auth type from service" so I wanted to turn on debugging so I could see what error is coming back from Exchange to try to see what the problem is.  So I added the following line at the top of the file that does the connection:
logging.getLogger('exchangelib').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
and re-ran the test but I'm not sure where the actual log output is written to?  I know this is probably a dumb question but couldn't find the output anywhere.  Thanks for any help
Tried to get the output log file to display in the same directory where I was running the tests from but no file was created.

That's for you to decide in your logging config. You can direct logging to stdout, to a file, or to something else. The most basic config is logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG). You'll need that for your logging statement to. work because Python won't log anything belof INFO level by default. See more about Python logging in https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html.
For exchangelib specifically, there are some helpful logging hints at https://ecederstrand.github.io/exchangelib/#troubleshooting
